# How to use a word at end of function signature?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to write a delegate interface like this:

```
// This delegate is just a sample. It could be any delegate.
// What's important here is the third function's signature.
protocol MyViewDelegate {
    func myView(_ myView: MyView, didDoSomething something: String)
    func myView(_ myView: MyView, didDoAnotherThing thing: String at: Date)
    func myView(_ myView: MyView, didDoYetSomethingElse)
}
```

However, the **third function** is invalid syntax. It's used to notify the delegate that some specific event happened, so the signature is important and I want to keep all function signatures consistent.

**Question:** What's the recommended signature for the third function?

Comment: So what's the *specific* issue? It sounds like you already *know* how to use delegates. But because you can only provide "sample" code it's quite hard to actually help you....

Comment: You can have parameters of a void type `()`, but there is seldom a good reason to use them

Comment: @dfd This is not about delegates. The question title and the goal say it: "How to use a word at the end of a function signature? The goal is for a method signature to be expressive." The delegate here is just the context and the reason why I would want a word at the end of a method signature: to be consistent with the naming of the other delegate methods. I apologize for not being explicit about this.

Comment: To me it sounds like you should be using Obj-C then. Part of it's design - as opposed to how Swift was designed - is just that. Expressiveness. To try to fit a square peg (in this case Swift) to fit in a round hole (in this case dynamic expressiveness in function names) is not something easily done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be very satisfying, but you simply can't do that. There is lots of precedent for writing these kinds of methods like this:

```
func myViewDidAskUserName(_ myView: MyView)
```

For example, a common one from Apple:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to give the delegate a choice of two kinds of thing that happened: said something, or asked user name. That sort of choice among possibilities, in Swift, is an *enum*:

```
enum WhatHappened {
    case didSaySomething(String)
    case didAskUserName
}
```

Now write your method signature like this:

```
protocol MyViewDelegate {
    func myView(_ myView: MyView, _ whatHappened: WhatHappened)
}
```

The method can be called by saying

```
myView(theView, .didSaySomething("hello"))
```

or by saying

```
myView(theView, .didAskUserName)
```

Comment: That is creative :) I'll keep this solution in mind. It won't apply to this specific project, unfortunately because the delegate may become larger with more methods and different signatures.